# How To add image in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to add image in JTable cell?

I have tried the image icon but it's written String in place of the image class

is there any way to do this thing?

Comment: what is the problem with this question and answer i have face so many difficulty to do this particular  thing....and with the Aim of help to other i have put this here and you are give negative point to this question and answer ................why?

Comment: First thing you should do in your post is mention that it is a self-answer question. Other wise people will look just at the question as it is. In it's current state it is a horribly asked question, that's probably why all the down-votes. People don't know that you are going to be the one to answer it.

Comment: ok i don't know how it's being done so ...and sorry for that my mistake but this content is really used full for the all learners

Comment: please help to vote up because this is real good one question and answer after the effort of 2 days i got this real good one answer and easy solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that particular thing via overriding following method in table model

```
    DefaultTableModel dTable= new DefaultTableModel(0, 0)
    {
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) 
        {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Q How to add image in JTable?

I have describe easy way to solve my above Question
.
 override the method of getColumnClass () of the table.

```
        tblTaskList = new JTable() ;

        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0)
        {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
             //override and give class value
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) 
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            };
        };
   //set Image in ImageIcon’s object   
   ImageIcon imgStart = new ImageIcon("start.png");
  ImageIcon imgStop = new ImageIcon("stop.png");
   ImageIcon imgPause = new ImageIcon("pause.png");

   for (int count = 1; count <= 30; count++) {
   //add row dynamically
        dm.addRow(new Object[] { count, "Task Title",    imgStart, imgPause,
                imgStop, "Status" });

    }
 tblTaskList.setModel(dm);
 //Add table in to the JScrollpane
                  JScrollPane jspTasklist = new JScrollPane(tblTaskList);
        //Add Scroll Pane into the frame
                  frmTaskList.getContentPane().add(jspTasklist);
```

Comment: `getColumnClass` should be overriden on the `TableModel` and _not_ the `JTable`

Comment: what is the problem with this question and answer i have face so many difficulty to do this particular  thing....and with the Aim of help to other i have put this here and you are give negative point to this question and answer

Comment: Your solution _may_ work, but it is done incorrectly. I did not down-vote, but I'm sure that is why whoever gave you the down-vote gave it to you. As I mentioned in my first comment, `getColumnClass` should be overriden in the `XxxTableModel` and _not_ on the `JTable` itself. If you don't know what a `TableModel` is, I suggest you take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Sorry for my that mistake but now is this perfect answer?

Comment: please help to vote up because this is real good one question and answer after the effort of 2 days i got this real good one answer and easy solution

Comment: You need to fix your indentation to at least make your answer readable. I still gave you your upvote